# Compare array[i].response to string passed via function argument

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains

```
const submissions = [{
  question: 'blah blah blah blah',
  response: 'response goes here'
},
```

I have a function that takes submission array and string. I need to check the response submissions[i].response against the string. if present return true.

```js
let submissions = [{
  question: 'blah blah blah blah',
  response: 'response goes here'
}];

function checkString(submissions, string) {
  for (let i = 0; i < submissions.length; i++) {
    if (submissions[i].response === string) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(checkString(submissions,'response goes here'));
```

If function is called checkString(submissions, 'response goes here') should return true. This always returns false.

Comment: your code seems correct; have you tried debugging the code? check if `string` and `subsmissions[i].response` match using `console.log`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me as well. Check jsbin: https://jsbin.com/bizawicajo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @ggorlen— *some* doens't require `!!`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function which will check if the `array` `response` contains the `string` you are checking.

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

```js
let submissions = [{
  question: 'blah blah blah blah',
  response: 'response goes here'
}];


var checkStr = submissions.some(i => i.response.includes('response goes here'));

console.log(checkStr)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still learning and this was very helpful!

Comment: @AlbertGonzalez Glad to help. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

you can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

in your [code snippet](https://jsbin.com/wubibuquva/edit?html,css,js,output) you want to check if the string is present in the response your code is not working because you are using `===` so My edit is to use `includes`

ECMAScript 6 or Later:

```
booleanResult = submissions.some(e => e.response.includes(string))
```

ECMAScript 5:

```
booleanResult = submissions.some(function (e) {
  return e.response.includes(string);
});
```

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.